# How do you clear the USB cache on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, usb, cache

In Vista / Windows 7 it was the `infcache.1` file you deleted and magically your USB devices worked again once connected.

This doesn't seem to exist in Windows 8 so I'm wondering what the alternative is? I have a drive that doesn't work in one port and it's down to Windows being stupid (yet) again.

Comment: CacheSet from sysinternals should work in a situation like this.

Comment: @Ramhound wrong question? He asks about the Infache file in Driverstore folder and not about the NTFS Metafile cache in RAM. 

Eric Cantor maybe MSFT optimized the procedure so that the cache is no longer needed.

Comment: @Ramhound how is that meant to work? Input would be greatly appreciated